# How can I create a subtle 3D effect like on Apple's iOS time selection wheel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, interface-design, ios

I'm trying to reproduce this subtle 3D effect on the Apple time and date selection wheel. How can I do this in Adobe Illustrator?

[image: Apple iOS selection wheel]

Comment: The lines are distorted in perspective, so that's what you'll have to do to reproduce it.

Comment: I would not call this effect "subtle" :P Maybe if the 'cylinder' was much larger, so the distortion would be far less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naty's answer is close but since you're looking for the "correct distortion of a cylinder", you should use an actual cylinder. Illustrator has very limited (and sometimes buggy) 3D tools available, but this is a case where it has just what you need.

In short, you should 3D extrude a circle and map the text around the cylinder that is created. To do this:

#### 1. Create your text, make it a Symbol

To do that, just select the text and either drag it to the Symbols pane or click the New Symbol button.

[image: creating a Symbol in Illustrator]

#### 2. Create a circle, 3D Extrude it

Select the circle, use <kbd>Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel...</kbd>

[image: Illustrator 3D Extrude & Bevel Options] [image: a 3D cylinder]

#### 3. Map your symbol to the face of the cylinder

Click the Map Art... button, select the correct surface (the rectangular one), and apply your symbol

[image: Illustrator Map Art panel]

#### 4. Set the "Surface" to "No Shading"

This is a dropdown in the "3D Extrude & Bevel Options"

[image: imitation Apple date selection wheel]

And you're done! You can play around with the "Perspective" setting in the 3D Extrude & Bevel options to find the right level of distortion for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll open by saying that **this is something that you should do on photoshop**, but if you insist on illustrator here is how it goes:

1. Create the type, separated into 3 objects - top, middle and bottom:
   [image]
2. Go to the top group, create outlines, make it a compound path (object>compound path>make) and give it a 3d rotate effect like in the image (the 20 degrees is my suggestion you can do more or less but leave the other attributes as I wrote them):
   [image]
3. Expand the image (object> expand appearance) and change the color to a gradient:
   [image]
4. Use guides to fit it to it's place and then do the same to the bottom part.
   [image]

Comment: Great Help! Still wondering why wondering you would prefer to do something like that in Photoshop? As this is just a piece in a larger design which is very vector based.

Comment: In general - Web design is done in Photoshop, even vector based web design is done in Photoshop - understanding why is an entirely different question. Now specific this entire explanation would have taken 2 easier steps in Photoshop.

Comment: This is on the right track but not quite correct. I've added an answer to show how to map the art to a cylinder to get the correct perspective.

Comment: @Benedikt you're right in thinking this should be done in Illustrator. My rule of thumb is: anything that _can_ be vector _should_ be vector; as shown this can easily be created in Illustrator. Photoshop has poor vector support in comparison to Illustrator and should not be the tool of choice for vector editing.